# Compound CS in WKT, with missing authority ID

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text

I'm trying to define a compound coordinate system, made by a horizontal CS and a vertical datum, using OGC WKT.

Apparently, an EPSG CRS code for the combined system does not exist. What should I do with the AUTHORITY field of the Compound CS (last line of the example below)? Should I simply remove it? Is it a problem for a CS not to have such field?

```py
COMPD_CS["IGM95 / UTM zone 33N + Genoa 1942 height",
    PROJCS["IGM95 / UTM zone 33N",
        GEOGCS["IGM95",
            DATUM["Istituto_Geografico_Militaire_1995",
                SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
                TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
            UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","4670"]],
        PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
        PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
        PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
        PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
        PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
        PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
        UNIT["metre",1,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
        AXIS["Easting",EAST],
        AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","3065"]],
    VERT_CS["Genoa 1942 height",
        VERT_DATUM["Genoa 1942",2005,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","1051"]],
        UNIT["metre",1,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
        AXIS["Gravity-related height",UP],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","5214"]],
 AUTHORITY["EPSG","????"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`AUTHORITY["WXYZ","????"]` is not required for WKT.

Note the Authority need not be EPSG, EPSG is just one of the possible Authorities

For some examples see the [Geographic information — Well-known text representation of coordinate reference systems standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html#127)

i.e.

**15.2   Examples of WKT describing a compound CRS**

> EXAMPLE 3      Spatio-temporal compound CRS (ellipsoid axis unit is
> metres as  is omitted):

```
COMPOUNDCRS["2D GPS position with civil time in ISO 8601 format",

  GEOGCRS["WGS 84 (G1762)",

    DYNAMIC[FRAMEEPOCH[2005]],

    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)",

      ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],

    CS[ellipsoidal,2],

      AXIS["(lat)",north,ORDER[1]],

      AXIS["(lon)",east,ORDER[2]],

      ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]

  ],

  TIMECRS["DateTime",

    TDATUM["Gregorian Calendar"],

  CS[TemporalDateTime,1],AXIS["Time (T)",future]

  ]

]
```